# Cant assign value to cell in multiindex dataframe (assigning to copy / slice of df?)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multi-index

I am trying to assign a value (mean of values in another column) to a cell in a multi-index Pandas dataframe over which I iterate to calculate means over a moving window in a different column. But, when I try to assign the value it doesn't change.

I am not used to working with multi-indexes and have solved several other problems but this one has me stumped for now...

Toy code that reproduces the problem:

```py
tuples = [
    ('AFG', 1963), ('AFG', 1964), ('AFG', 1965), ('AFG', 1966), ('AFG', 1967), ('AFG', 1968),
    ('BRA', 1963), ('BRA', 1964), ('BRA', 1965), ('BRA', 1966), ('BRA', 1967), ('BRA', 1968)
    ]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)
values = [[12, None], [0, None],
          [12, None], [0, 4], 
          [12, 5], [0, 4], 
          [12, 2], [0, 4], 
          [12, 2], [0, 4], 
          [1, 4], [7, 1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=['Oil', 'Pop'], index=index)
lag =-2
lead=0
indicator = 'Pop'
new_indicator = 'Mean_pop'
df[new_indicator] = np.nan
df
```

Gives:

```py
               Oil  Pop Mean_pop
AFG     1963    12  NaN NaN
        1964    0   NaN NaN
        1965    12  NaN NaN
        1966    0   4.0 NaN
        1967    12  5.0 NaN
        1968    0   4.0 NaN
BRA     1963    12  2.0 NaN
        1964    0   4.0 NaN
        1965    12  2.0 NaN
        1966    0   4.0 NaN
        1967    1   4.0 NaN
        1968    7   1.0 NaN
```

Then to iterate over the df:

```py
for country, country_df in df.groupby(level=0):
    oldestyear = country_df[indicator].first_valid_index()[1]
    latestyear =  country_df[indicator].last_valid_index()[1]
    for t in range(oldestyear, latestyear+1):
        print (country, oldestyear, latestyear, t)
        print ("  For",  country, ", calculate mean over ", t+lag, "to", t+lead, 
               "and add to row for year", t)
        dftt = country_df.loc[(country, t+lag):(country, t+lead)]
        print(dftt[indicator])
        mean = dftt[indicator].mean(axis=0)
        print("mean for ", indicator, "in", country, "during", t+lag, "to", t+lead, "is", mean)
        df.loc[country, t][new_indicator] = mean
```

Diagnostic output not pasted, but df looks the same after iterating over it and I get the following warning on some iterations:

```py
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  if sys.path[0] == '':
```

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a easy as setting last line to:

```
df.loc[(country, t), new_indicator] = mean
```